# Can I raise and handle exceptions in the same function

Tags: custom-exceptions

I am raising an exception and trying to handle the exception in snippet. The raising exception part and handling exception part are done in a function. Is it wrong to do so?

```
import sys

def water_level(lev):
    if(lev<10):
        raise Exception("Invalid Level!") 

    print"New level=" # If exception not raised then print new level
    lev=lev+10
    print lev

    try:
        if(level<10):
            print"Alarming situation has occurred."
    except Exception:
        sys.stdout.write('\a')
        sys.stdout.flush()

    else:   
        os.system('say "Liquid level ok"')

print"Enter the level of tank"
level=input()
water_level(level) #function call
```

The output is not handling exception. Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to just raise the exception in the function and then catch it it when you call the function so your function does not do too much and your error handling is independent. And it makes your code simpler.

Your code never reached your `except` clause because if the water level is too low it raises an exception and jumps out of the function and if it was okay it just reaches the `else` clause. The `print` statement in your `try` clause is also never reached because it is the same condition than the one that raises your exception and that one jumps out.

Your code should be something like that...

```
import sys
import os

def water_level(level):
  #just raise exception in function here
  if level < 10:
    raise Exception("Invalid Level!")

  level = level + 10

  print("New level=") # If exception not raised then print new level
  print(level)

#function call
print("Enter the level of tank")

#cast to int
level=int(input())

try:
    #call function in here
    water_level(level)

#catch risen exceptions
except Exception as e:
    sys.stdout.write('\a')
    sys.stdout.flush()

    #print exception(verification)
    print(e)

    print("Alarming situation has occurred.")
else:
    os.system('say "Liquid level ok"')
```

Note that i corrected some other flaws

- `import os` was missing
- you should cast your `input()` to a number so you can do number comparisions and additions
- try to avoid to catch the least specific Exception `Exception` because you will catch every other Exception too.(thats why i added the `print(e)`) -> think about custom exceptions

Comment: I need help in editing code when it gets typed on screen. My comments section gets big in size and some code is getting on same line,please help.

Comment: I don't really get what you want to say with your comment.